# How to detect image format in a stream

Tags: c#, .net

I need to detect Image format to save a image like image1.jpg, image2.gif, but i only have a stream, and i do not know the image format(gif, jpeg, png, etc)

Is there a way to detect imageformat from a stream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Image.FromStream` to load the image, then you can see what the `Image.RawFormat` is.